# AD7708 ADC SPI receive problem in STM32

Tags: stm32, adc, spi, stm32cubeide

I'm currently working on a ADC AD7708. There is not much document or library for this IC.  I'm writing ad7708 driver for stm32f446 mcu. In datasheet register structure of ad7708 shown as below:

[image]

I want to read the id of this IC first. Im using SPI for serial interface as the datasheet recommend. Func. for reading devices id:

```
uint8_t ad7708_areYouThere(ad7708_dev *dev){
uint8_t status = AD7708_OK;
uint8_t id;

status = ad7708_readReg(dev, ID_REG, &id, 1);

if ((id >> 4) == AD7708_ID)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return 1;
}}
```

I have register read function as shown below:

```
static StatusTypeDef ad7708_readReg(ad7708_dev *dev, SelectedReg reg, uint8_t *data, uint16_t len){
StatusTypeDef status = AD7708_OK;

status = setNextOperation(dev, reg, AD7708_Read, 1);

setCS(0);
status = spiRecieve(dev, data, len);
setCS(1);

return status;}
```

In the setNextOperation() func. im setting the communication register for upcoming read or write event.

```
static StatusTypeDef setNextOperation(ad7708_dev *dev, SelectedReg reg, uint8_t rw, uint16_t len){
StatusTypeDef status = AD7708_OK;

dev->commReg.bits.WEN = 0;
dev->commReg.bits.RW = rw;
dev->commReg.merged.zeros = 0; // must be 0 !!!!!!!!
dev->commReg.merged.addr = reg;

setCS(0);
status = spiTransmit(dev, &dev->commReg.byte, len);
setCS(1);
dev->commReg.bits.WEN = 1;

return status;}
```

im using HAL library for spi recieve and transmit.

```
static StatusTypeDef spiRecieve(ad7708_dev *dev, uint8_t *data, uint16_t len) {
StatusTypeDef status = AD7708_OK;

if (HAL_SPI_Receive(&dev->intf, data, len) != AD7708_OK)
{
    status = AD7708_ERROR;
}

return status;}

static StatusTypeDef spiTransmit(ad7708_dev *dev, uint8_t *data, uint16_t len){
StatusTypeDef status = AD7708_OK;

if (HAL_SPI_Transmit(&dev->intf, data, len, 200) != AD7708_OK)
{
    status = AD7708_ERROR;
}

return status;}
```

But i cant read any register value with these functions. I dont get any error code neither. Did i not understand clearly the register structure. Is there any chance that im using wrong HAL spi transmit/receive functions? How can i solve this problem?
Then i write a basic transmit-recive func. in while loop just for simplifie the situation.

```
  while (1){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, 0);
    status = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &txdata, 1, 200);
    while (hspi1.State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY)1;

    status = HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &rxdata, 1, 200);
    while (hspi1.State != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, 1);

    HAL_Delay(10);
/* USER CODE END WHILE */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */}
and then i examined with scope. here is the results:
```

[image]

CH1 belongs to the SCK line and CH1 belongs to the MOSI line. I can see that 0b01001111 tranmistted trough the line. But i dont see anything in MISO line as shown here:

[image]

Comment: What do you see for activity using your logic analyzer?  Post the screenshots.

Comment: i edited the post you can see the scope results. @ChrisKnudsen

Comment: The scope traces are _concerning_.  Did you use a ground lead when taking these measurements?  Is so, then there is something wrong with SPI bus configuration on the uC (spi bus pins defined properly?) or wiring (missing ground ref?), as your signals should not be floating above ground like that.  Google for some typical SPI bus signals for a reference.

Comment: im using stm32 nucleo board as my mcu so there is not much chance to problem with grounding. Then i double checked my all pins to be sure and there is no problem with my hardware i suppose. I  think hese traces not good beacuse of my test system. I will share my spi settings. Maybe there was a problem with these setttings. @ChrisKnudsen

Comment: Which Nucleo board has an AD7708 on it?  What are any external connections that you have to the Nucleo board?  What is the part number of the Nucleo board?  If the AD7708 is externally connected, then a simple schematic is needed.